# rsync transfer to remote machine syntax for windows

Tags: windows, rsync

I have to transfer (and keep synched) two folders through rsync.
My problem is I always get an error on the remote folder, which I double checked is correct and existing.
Command line I use is:

```
rsync -rtvIz --chmod=ugo=rwX /cygdrive/c/aus/testrsync/sync remote.server.intranet:/cygdrive/d/testrsync
```

Error I receive is:
**rsync: Failed to exec ssh: No such file or directory (2)**

The following command line, using a shared folder on remote DeltaCopy works fine:

```
rsync -rtvIz --chmod=ugo=rwX /cygdrive/c/aus/testrsync/sync remote.server.intranet::EBackup
```

Answer (score 1):

It may depend upon exactly what version of rsync you are using on the server side but I don't specify /cygdrive paths for my server path. Using the rsync protocol at least I set the remote URI as `rsync://MACHINE:/Dirname/Subdir` but I do have to use /cygdrive type paths for the local paths. Then on the Windows server machine that hosts the rsyncd the rsyncd.conf cygwin style paths. eg:

```
[Builds]
comment = Automated build output
path = /cygdrive/e/Builds
read only = yes
list
```

This allows normal rsync uri's to be used by clients and the server can then translate these into something it can access on the local filesystem.

Comment: Thanks, but in my configuration also the destination machine is windows. I want to specify the path and not a configured rsync share. My rsync version is 3.0.4